# ContentProvider/ContentResolver Query Sorting by ID by default

Tags: android, sqlite

I am working on an application that stores everything in a database and it is accessed using a ContentProvider. My scenario is as follows:

- I make a web call and receive a list of integers which represent the ids of the objects I need to retrieve from my database on the device.
- I make a call to ContentResolver.query() with the following Selection:

  Selection: _id=? OR _id=? OR _id=?

  Selection Ids: 30; 165; 149;
- So, I need to get all items where the id is either 30, 165, or 149. And I need them *in that exact order*.

This is the exact call I am making on the ContentResolver:

```
Cursor cursor = mActivity.getContentResolver().query(myUri, null, selection, selectionIds, null);
```

As you can see, I do not pass in any sorting. However, the result gives me a Cursor with the order being the following: 30, 149, 165. So, it appears it is defaulting the sorting by _id even though I do not specify any sort order. My question is, does anyone know of a way to stop this from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you select rows, from any database, without specifying an ORDER BY clause, you should consider the order of the results as undefined, i.e. it could come back in any order. The reason you are seeing it sorted by _id here is just due to circumstance - they are likely to be in that order on the underlying database files so that is the order SQLite reads them back in. However it is not safe to assume that will always be so.

So the actual answer to your question is no, you can't assume SQLite will return your rows in any particular order without an ORDER BY clause. If you are unable to provide such a clause (which appears to be the case here) you'll have to sort them in code after getting all the data from the cursor.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for taking the time to explain. I will just sort the way I want them to be after I get them from the database. I had assumed it would be as is but that was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is not defaulting to `_id`, it is giving you the records as they are in the db (which happen to be sorted by id). Pass your own sorting order if you don't want this.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I said in the other answer, I assumed they would come out in the order I asked for them, but that was an incredibly wrong assumption. Thanks again.